# Add git commit id in fat jar manifest using sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, fatjar

I am using sbt-assembly plugin to build a fat Jar for my scala project. Is there a way I can include git commit id in the jar manifest, something similar to what `git-commit-id-plugin` does for maven.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Old question but there I go...

You could use [sbt-git](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git) plugin with sbt-assembly for including git information in your `MANIFEST.MF` file.

For adding information to your `MANIFEST.MF` file you can use the `packageOptions` sbt key in this way:

```
import sbt.Package.ManifestAttributes
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit.git
packageOptions := Seq(ManifestAttributes(("Repository-Commit", git.gitHeadCommit.value.get)))
```

See example over here: [spark-authorizer](https://github.com/gumartinm/SparkForFun/tree/c7090ec33677753ce281309b3814d9c1278defe6/spark-authorizer)

This information will be stored in your `MANIFEST.MF` file included in the fat jar generated by sbt-assembly :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Implementation-Title: spark-authorizer
Repository-Commit: 12538262c1be14800eb820163de6c46cdbd69c99
Implementation-Version: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Specification-Vendor: de.example.playground.spark.authorizer
Specification-Title: spark-authorizer
Implementation-Vendor-Id: de.example.playground.spark.authorizer
Specification-Version: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor: de.example.playground.spark.authorizer
```

You can add as many values as you want to `packageOptions`. All of them will be included in the MANIFEST.MF file.